# Background selection in hypergeometric test using diferent cell types

Tags: bioinformatics, hypergeometric-distribution

I have to select the background for an hypergeometric test that I have to perform. The problem is as follow:

I have a list of genes differentially expressed in cell B between "control vs treatment". I want to see if there is an overlap between the genes up regulated in this experiment with genes that are Up regulated between cell A vs cell B.  As you can notice the cell B is different from the cell A and I am wondering if there is a suitable strategy to handle this problem.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution, apparently GSEA would be better than a simply hypergeometric test.

More info: http://software.broadinstitute.org/gsea/index.jsp

Comment: Isn't GSEA commonly done by a simple hyper-geometric test?